# most of whose was from

Tags: relative-pronouns, whose

Oxford Modern English Grammar (OMEG) by Bas Aarts has these passages on [page 52](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=9Qn0DyUiKRUC&pg=PA52&dq=%22most%20of%20whose%20was%20from%20purse%20seiners%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAzc7EvYHYAhWBtpQKHdDIAvoQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q&f=true):

> ...
>   [image]
>   ...
>   [image]
>   ...
>   [image]
>   ...

Sentence (40) is apparently taken from an Independent article "[How Tuna Conquered the World](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/food-and-drink/features/how-tuna-conquered-the-world-1700127.html)". Two prior paragraphs along with Sentence (40) are shown here:

> Some populations, such as leatherback turtles, are being heavily
>   damaged; pushed to the brink of extinction, even though they are not
>   being hunted. Purse seine boats that drop giant drawstring nets in
>   tuna areas, and "long-liners" which sink lines of up to 80km, hooked
>   with bait, are the biggest by-catch culprits.
>
> Conservationists say pole and line fishing, where boats drops bait
>   into the sea and fishermen claw the tuna into the boat (avoiding other
>   species), are "cleaner" methods.
>
> In a report from Greenpeace last year, and still available online,
>   retailers and canning companies were ranked in order of their
>   tuna-fishing policies. Sainsbury, Co-op and Marks & Spencer came top;
>   Princes and John West – most of whose was from purse seiners – came
>   bottom.

Sentence (40) from OMEG is the same as the last paragraph shown above.

Is this "independent" use of *whose* grammatical? 
If so, is it natural English or should *tuna* be added after *whose* as follows to make it more natural?

> In a report from Greenpeace last year, and still available online,
>   retailers and canning companies were ranked in order of their
>   tuna-fishing policies. Sainsbury, Co-op and Marks & Spencer came top;
>   Princes and John West – most of whose **tuna** was from purse seiners – came
>   bottom.

Comment: No, it looks very odd, and, yes, 'most of whose tuna' is much clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage is uncommon but grammatical in a non-defining relative clause. A simpler text makes this clear:

> Sainsbury gets its tuna from the Atlantic; John West, most of whose is from the Pacific, ... .

The problem in the present case is that the relative pronoun *whose* is far removed from its antecedent *tuna*.  A careful writer would have recognized the potential ambiguity caused by this separation and simply repeated the antecedent:

> Sainsbury, Co-op and Marks & Spencer came top; Princes and John West – most of whose *tuna* was from purse seiners – came bottom.

Comment: Thanks. The added 'tuna' is treated as singular. Why? And can it ever be treated as plural?

Comment: @JK2. Yes, if _tuna_ is conceived as being the 'flesh' of the fish that is eaten, then it is singular. E.g., _Tuna is my favourite sandwich filling_. If _tuna_ is conceived as the individual fish, then it can be pluralized: _The tuna were detected by echolocation and 300 of them were captured in the dragnet_.

Comment: Thanks. In the context of the Independent article, I would think their tuna would mean what they captured from purse seiners. Then, shouldn't it have been in the plural in the original text? _most of whose tuna **were** from purse seiners_ And in your example text? _Sainsbury gets its tuna from the Atlantic; John West, most of whose **are** from the Pacific..._

Comment: @JK2. Good question. In the second paragraph of the full text you cite, the reference is clearly to tuna as individual fish (i.e. plural tuna). In the last paragraph the writer employs the singular concept of tuna as 'flesh'. This is rather careless writing, compounded by the omission of _tuna_ after _whose_.